# Map linux commands Cygwin

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, cygwin

I have installed on cygwin a mercury compiler but the comand to invoke it is *mmc module_name* but mmc calls Microsoft Management Console.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you could edit your `~.bashrc` to contain something like

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

This will also prevent problems with `find.exe` being used from Windows (ick) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can alias mmc in your .bashrc:

alias mmc "/path/to/mercurycompiler"